# Looking for a particular Enumerable operator sequence: TakeWhile(!) + Concat Single

Tags: c#, linq

Given an Enumerable, I want to Take() all of the elements up to and including a terminator (throwing an exception if the terminator is not found). Something like:

```
list.TakeWhile(v => !condition(v)).Concat(list.Single(condition))
```

..except not crappy. Only want to walk it once.

Is this concisely possible with current operators in .NET 4 and Rx or do I need to write a new operator?

Writing the operator would take me less time than it did to write this question (though I think half that time would be figuring out what to name this function), but I just don't want to duplicate something that's already there.

**Update**

Ok, here's the operator. Very exciting, I know. Anyway, possible to build it from built-in operators?

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeThroughTerminator<T>([NotNull] this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, bool> isTerminatorTester)
    {
        foreach (var item in @this)
        {
            yield return item;
            if (isTerminatorTester(item))
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Terminator not found in list");
    }
```

Comment: I'd just write an operator to do the job...

Comment: I'd agree - you probably could use a clever `Zip()` for a look-ahead but that still would traverse the enumeration twice - operator is the way to go.

Comment: Btw, what is your take on the fact, that lots of items get yielded before we even know if we are ever allowed to use these items (i.e. an exception is not thrown)?

Comment: Well, I guess it's still the best one can do in most cases, even with streaming enumerables. Then again, if it is streaming you can't really do work on the items until there has been no confirmation on a successful selection. Somewhat unsatisfactory. A completely safe solution would always have to check for success before yielding them out. (streaming in the sense of "expensive retrieval from some source")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a builtin to do such an operation efficiently.  It's not very often that people would need to get items that satisfy a condition and one more that doesn't.  You'd have to write it yourself.

However you can build this up using existing methods, it just won't be as efficient since you'd need to keep the state somehow only complicating your code.  I wouldn't condone this sort of query as it goes against the philosophy of LINQ and would write it myself.  But since you asked:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
Func<int, bool> condition = i => i != 5;
int needed = 1;
var query = list.Where(item => condition(item)
                                   ? needed > 0
                                   : needed-- > 0)
                .ToList(); // this might cause problems
if (needed != 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence is not properly terminated");
```

However this has its own problems which can't really be resolved nicely.  The right way to deal with this is to code this all by hand (without LINQ).  This will give you the exact same behavior.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileSingleTerminated<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    var hasTerminator = false;
    var terminator = default(TSource);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!hasFailed)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
                yield return item;
            else
            {
                hasTerminator = true;
                terminator = item;
            }
        }
        else if (!predicate(item))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains more than one terminator");
    }
    if (!hasTerminator)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence is not terminated");
    yield return terminator;
}
```

---

After much thinking about this, I would say it would be difficult to get the most efficient implementation of the original query since it has conflicting requirements.  You're mixing `TakeWhile()` which terminates early with `Single()` which cannot.  It would be possible to replicate the end result (as we all have attempted here) but the behavior cannot without making nontrivial changes to the code.  If the goal was to take only the first failing item, then this would be totally possible and replicable, however since it isn't, you'll just have to deal with the problems that this query has.

p.s., I think it's evident how non-trivial this is to do just by how many edits I have made on this answer alone.  Hopefully this is my last edit.

Comment: This makes it difficult to throw an exception if the terminator was not found though. Don't think list really always is a list. See my answer

Comment: @skarmats: The actual type of the "list" is irrelevant, just as long as it's an `IEnumerable<T>`.  Initially my primary goal for this query was to get as much efficiency out of this as possible and terminate as soon as possible.  Now I see that it is not possible and will have to go through the entire collection at least once.

Comment: @Jeff M: My mumbling about list was born from the thought that one could do some comparison on .Count to see if we need to throw an exception. Along the lines of "did not find terminator" && "count is equal to source". What I don't like about the operator solution is, that one enumerates lots of items and then possibly throws them all away on exception (all our solutions do this as well, of course...). See my question on the question post.

Comment: @skarmats: You've made me see the light.  At first I thought that this could be done relatively easily but now that you've (rightly) brought up the other conditions, I've come to the conclusion that this problem just will not have a nice solution period.

Comment: @Jeff M: It is almost as if it was a deliberate decision by the framework designers, that all methods that can throw an exception in such a scenario, also only can return 1 item from the source. There is no problem associated with that. Well, anyway. Thanks for the back and forth, I wouldn't have given much thought to this on my own.

Comment: Your latest version of this post has a markedly different behavior from the original query though. Doing it like this, it will fail late. The original will fail fast. The .Single() in the original query is executed first - before any enumeration begins.

Comment: @skarmats: The original query I was referring to was the one made up of combining `TakeWhile()` and `Single()`. It doesn't actually work as it was written but I think the intent was clear. It will enumerate through the items that satisfy the `TakeWhile()`, then attempt to take the single satisfying condition possibly failing then. Unfortunately `Concat()` appends sequences, not individual items so it would fail at the end since the second gets enumerated after the first. I'm going to leave it at that, I've spend enough time on this. :) (And now I just realized I have the conditions reversed)

Comment: @Jeff M: Yes, the original query doesn't compile. And yes, if you write it like .Concat(list.Where(cond).Take(1)) you are right - it will be lazily evaluated. But in order to keep close to the original pseudo-query, I used .Single() as close to the original statement as possible. Basically via new T[]. If you don't hide the .Single() away in some yield return, it will always be evaluated immediately.

Comment: @Jeff M: I know what you mean though - it probably was not what the author had in mind... But what I am saying is, any one of the First/Single class of methods act like ToList in that they are immediately evaluated if not hidden away artificially.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some hardcore if you don't want to write your own operator:

```
var input = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var condition = new Func<int, bool>(i => i < 5);

bool terminatorPassed = false;
var condition2 = new Func<int, bool>(i =>
        {
            try { return !terminatorPassed; }
            finally { terminatorPassed = !condition(i); }
        });

var result = input.TakeWhile(condition2).ToArray();
if (!terminatorPassed) throw new FutureException("John Connor survived");
```

Comment: This is really cool in a "I hope I never run into this at work" way.

Comment: I like it as well, it's not often one gets to abuse the finally statement. But, like my solution, it will always throw an exception if you don't execute the enumerable before the check.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use `TakeWhile()` in our solutions as it terminates too soon.  We need to verify that the entire sequence contains a single failing item (going by the logic of the original query).

Comment: In my opinion, going through everything first, is the only safe solution. You couldn't do any real work with so-far yielded items, if the enumerators might throw an exception in the end.

Comment: @skarmats, thanks for mentioning that, fixed the code to avoid exception caused by Linq laziness

Answer (score 0):

```
int? j = null;
var result = list.TakeWhile((o, i) =>
                        {
                          if (j == null && cond(o)) { j = i + 1; }
                          return (j ?? -1) != i;
                        });
if (j == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
```

I'd go for operator, but how can one ever be sure there really isn't a built-in way? ;-)

UPDATE1: Ok, my code is useless. I'd bet it always throws an exception, if execution of the Enumerable has not taken place before the check for the exception...